# Contents of URL coming back as nil

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am doing a fb request and when I try to turn the contents of URL into NSData it comes back as nil? I can't work out where i'm going wrong, my code is:

```
 func fbRequestCompletionHandler(connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!){
        if let gotError = error{
            //got error
        }
        else{

            let email = result["email"]
            let firstName = result["first_name"]
            let userFBID = result["id"]
            println(userFBID) //PRINTS THE CORRECT ID
            let userImageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(userFBID)/picture?type=small"

            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: userImageURL)

            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

            println(imageData) //PRINTS AS NIL
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `NSData`'s `init` method taking a URL is defined as:

```
init?(contentsOfURL url: NSURL)
```

The `?` means it returns an optional type, so the return value could be `nil`.  You could determine what the problem is using:

```
var error: NSError?
if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: NSDataReadingOptions(0), error: &error) {
    // Success
}
else {
    println("An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```